# Return the Specified Fields and the _id Field Only in java

Tags: java, mongodb, crud, pojo, map-projections

UPDATE: Spuggiehawk advised in his answer to fix the `include` keyword issue, and also suggest an alternative way to get the `_id` other than `projections`. However, I still have trouble to call this method from my service class, which edit the user detail, that I must admit I have limited knowledge to make it right.

```
@Override
public User get(Object userId) {

    FindIterable<User> userTbl = database.getCollection("User", User.class).find();

User user = new User();

for (User doc : userTbl) {
    
    String oid = doc.getId().toHexString();

    System.out.println("_id = " + oid); 
        
        return user;
    }

    return null;
}
```

In the Service class

```
public void editUser() {
    
    String userId = request.getParameter("id");
    
    User user = userDAO.get(userId);
    
    System.out.println(user.getFullName());     
}
```

Comment: Can you add the prompt `prompted me create another method with string` in the question

Comment: You were prompted to create the include method because the compiler couldn't find the actual include method you want to use. Can you use Projections.include("email") in place of include function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use projection if you just want the object ID.  The syntax you want to get that (in a loop) is:

```
    FindIterable<Document> userTbl = db.getCollection("User").find();
    for (Document doc: userTbl2)
    {
        String id = doc.getObjectId("_id").toString();
        System.out.println("_id = " + id);
    }
```

Do what you need to with that id value.

As far as your use of include is concerned, if you do find a situation where you need that, then you need the static import.  Eclipse should give you the option if you hover over the keyword:

[image: Static import in Eclipse]

If Eclipse doesn't show that, you might need to add the references in your Eclipse configuration under Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Favorites:

[image: Eclipse static import packages]

The important part is at the top of your code, it should include:

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.include;
```

You'll find that useful for your filters too, eg.

```
Bson filter = eq("email", "email.com");
db.getCollection("User").find(filter);
```

Finally, if you only want to get the first matching record in your find(), use:

```
Document = db.getCollection("User").find(filter).first();
```

Comment: I could change it to `FindIterable<User> userTbl = database.getCollection("User", User.class).find();` if using POJO, right? Somehow I got  `null` when calling from my Service class but.

Comment: I don't have the option to choose either `include` or `eq` method when I hover over the keyword.

Comment: You can add the "import static com...." by hand at the top of the file.  But it does make life easier if you update the Content Assist values.  More details here: http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/02/01/generate-static-imports-in-eclipse-on-autocomplete/